# (Prolog) Parsing Lisp s-expressions Into Prolog Terms

Tags: parsing, prolog, lisp, dcg, s-expression

I have written a parser in Prolog that takes a tokenized list and should return an expression where the variable is unified with the value of the evaluated equation:

```
Tokens = ['(', is, v('X',3),'(', +, 1, 2, ')', ')' ]
Expr = (3 is 1 + 2)
```

At present, my parser is returning the following:

```
Expr [is, _G32432, '(', +, 1, 2, ')'|_G19343]
```

Does anyone have an idea for how I can fix this parser? I have included the code below:

```
%Definite Clause Grammar (DCG) for Lisp s-expressions
expression(N) --> atom(N).
expression(N) --> integer(N).
expression(N) --> variable(N).
expression(N) --> list(N).
list(N) --> ['('], sequence(N), [')'].
sequence(_) --> [].
sequence([H|T]) --> expression(H), sequence(T).
%atom(_) --> [].
atom(N) --> [N],{atom(N)}.
%variable(_) --> [].
variable(N) --> [v(_,N)],{var(N)}.
%integer(_) --> [].
integer(N) --> [N],{integer(N)}.    

evaluate(String, Expr):-
tokenize(String, Tokens),
expression(Expr,Tokens,[]),
write('Expression: '), write_term(Expr, [ignore_ops(true)]).
```

EDIT: Below is my working version of the parser:

```
expression(N) --> atom(N).    %an atom is a type of expression
expression(N) --> integer(N). %an integer is a type of expression
expression(N) --> variable(N). %a variable is a type of expression
expression(M) --> list(N),{M=..N}.  
list(N) --> ['('], sequence(N), [')'].   %a sequence within parens is a type of list
sequence([]) --> [].                 %a sequence can be empty
sequence([H|T]) --> expression(H), sequence(T).  %a sequence can be composed of an expression
% sequence([]) --> []. %and a sequence atom(_) --> [].
atom(N) --> [N],{atom(N),N \= '(', N \= ')'}. %parens are not atoms, but all other Prolog atoms 
% If N is a variable and it is within the v(Label,X) data structure,
% then it is a var in this grammar
variable(N) --> [v(_,N)],{var(N)}.
%variable(_) --> [].
%integer(_) --> [].
integer(N) --> [N],{integer(N)}.
```

Comment: The suggestions in the below comment did not fix my problem, unfortunately. See my edit for the final fixed version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your input tokens is [1]. Notice that it will never match your rule [2] since `N` is an integer and not a variable (also, `'X'` is an atom and not a variable).

```
[1]   v('X',3)
[2]   variable(N) --> [v(_,N)],{var(N)}.
```

Changing [2] to [3] fixes this problem.

```
[3]   variable(N) --> [N], {var(N)}.
```

PS: Also make sure you close the resulting expression in the base case for `sequence//1` by replacing the corresponding line with [4].

```
[4]   sequence([]) --> [].
```